# How to sort objects collection based on multiple condition?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I am trying to fix the sort using map method so I created separate variables for `mappedData` and `sortedData`. The problem is I am not getting the values sorted.

The third object has 'a' values, so it should be sorted in ascending.

```
 const mappedData = data.map(number => {
    /* ... */
    number.sortColumn = "";
    if (number.animalNumbersRank) {
      number.sortColumn = number.animalNumbersRank[0].number;
    }
    console.log("number.sortColumn--->", number.sortColumn);
    console.log("number.heightValueStart--->", number.heightValueStart);

    return number;
  });
  const sortedData = mappedData.sort((a, b) => {
    /* ... */
    a.heightValueStart < b.heightValueStart
      ? -1
      : a.heightValueStart > b.heightValueStart
      ? 1
      : a.sortColumn < b.sortColumn
      ? -1
      : a.sortColumn > b.sortColumn
      ? 1
      : 0;
  });

  console.log("data--->", data);
  console.log("sortedData--->", sortedData);
```

```js
var data = [{
    animalrId: 11111111111,
    // "lionId": erer,
    uiuiuiId: "151856658687700",
    ddfdfdf: "2018-02-14 19:03:31",
    category: "wewe5454",
    organizationName: "apple boy",
    jioID: "fdkldfkl",
    jioIDType: "EIN",
    heightValueStart: "c",
    formattedjioID: "8989-23892389",
    lowerOrgName: "apple boy",
    animalNumbersRank: [{
      number: "c"
    }],
    dklfkldf: [{
      number: "1548267230"
    }],
    jkkklkl: [{
      number: "21468096",
      expired: "Y"
    }],
    sortColumn: "c"
  },

  {
    animalrId: 222222222222,
    lionId: 232323,
    uiuiuiId: "153920398625500",
    ddfdfdf: "2018-10-10 19:02:45",
    category: "wewe 2323",
    organizationName: "b",
    jioID: "fdkldfkl",
    jioIDType: "EIN",
    heightValueStart: "b",
    formattedjioID: "8989-23892389",
    lowerOrgName: "apple boy",
    sortColumn: ""
  },

  {
    animalrId: 33333333333,
    lionId: 232323,
    uiuiuiId: "153920398625500",
    ddfdfdf: "2018-10-10 19:02:45",
    category: "wewe 545445",
    organizationName: "apple boy",
    jioID: "fdkldfkl",
    jioIDType: "EIN",
    heightValueStart: "a",
    formattedjioID: "8989-23892389",
    lowerOrgName: "apple boy",
    animalNumbersRank: [{
      number: "a"
    }],
    dklfkldf: [{
      number: "1548267230"
    }],
    jkkklkl: [{
        number: "475255"
      },
      {
        number: "299993436",
        expired: "Y"
      }
    ],
    sortColumn: "a"
  }
];

const mappedData = data.map(number => {
  /* ... */
  number.sortColumn = "";
  if (number.animalNumbersRank) {
    number.sortColumn = number.animalNumbersRank[0].number;
  }
  console.log("number.sortColumn--->", number.sortColumn);
  console.log("number.heightValueStart--->", number.heightValueStart);

  return number;
});
const sortedData = mappedData.sort((a, b) => {
  /* ... */
  a.heightValueStart < b.heightValueStart ?
    -1 :
    a.heightValueStart > b.heightValueStart ?
    1 :
    a.sortColumn < b.sortColumn ?
    -1 :
    a.sortColumn > b.sortColumn ?
    1 :
    0;
});

console.log("data--->", data);
console.log("sortedData--->", sortedData);
```

Comment: You need to must `return` something in your function (`sortedData`)

Comment: You should not use nested ternary expressions. Instead of you need to use `if/else`, It much better and understandable the conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `sortedData` you don't return anything, You should `return` `0` or `1` or `-1`.

```
const sortedData = data.sort((a, b) => {
  let number = 0;
  if ((a.heightValueStart < b.heightValueStart) || (a.sortColumn < b.sortColumn)) {
    number = -1;
  } else if ((a.heightValueStart > b.heightValueStart) || (a.sortColumn > b.sortColumn)) {
    number = 1;
  }
  return number;
});
```

Check below snippet.

```js
const data = [
  {
    animalrId: 11111111111,
    // "lionId": erer,
    uiuiuiId: '151856658687700',
    ddfdfdf: '2018-02-14 19:03:31',
    category: 'wewe5454',
    organizationName: 'apple boy',
    jioID: 'fdkldfkl',
    jioIDType: 'EIN',
    heightValueStart: 'c',
    formattedjioID: '8989-23892389',
    lowerOrgName: 'apple boy',
    animalNumbersRank: [
      {
        number: 'c',
      },
    ],
    dklfkldf: [
      {
        number: '1548267230',
      },
    ],
    jkkklkl: [
      {
        number: '21468096',
        expired: 'Y',
      },
    ],
    sortColumn: 'c',
  },

  {
    animalrId: 222222222222,
    lionId: 232323,
    uiuiuiId: '153920398625500',
    ddfdfdf: '2018-10-10 19:02:45',
    category: 'wewe 2323',
    organizationName: 'b',
    jioID: 'fdkldfkl',
    jioIDType: 'EIN',
    heightValueStart: 'b',
    formattedjioID: '8989-23892389',
    lowerOrgName: 'apple boy',
    sortColumn: '',
  },

  {
    animalrId: 33333333333,
    lionId: 232323,
    uiuiuiId: '153920398625500',
    ddfdfdf: '2018-10-10 19:02:45',
    category: 'wewe 545445',
    organizationName: 'apple boy',
    jioID: 'fdkldfkl',
    jioIDType: 'EIN',
    heightValueStart: 'a',
    formattedjioID: '8989-23892389',
    lowerOrgName: 'apple boy',
    animalNumbersRank: [
      {
        number: 'a',
      },
    ],
    dklfkldf: [
      {
        number: '1548267230',
      },
    ],
    jkkklkl: [
      {
        number: '475255',
      },
      {
        number: '299993436',
        expired: 'Y',
      },
    ],
    sortColumn: 'a',
  },
];

const sortedData = data.sort((a, b) => {
  let number = 0;
  if ((a.heightValueStart < b.heightValueStart) || (a.sortColumn < b.sortColumn)) {
    number = -1;
  } else if ((a.heightValueStart > b.heightValueStart) || (a.sortColumn > b.sortColumn)) {
    number = 1;
  }
  return number;
});

console.log(sortedData);
```

Answer (score 1):

[image] you are missing return, try like this

```
const sortedData = mappedData.sort(function(a, b){
   if(a.heightValueStart < b.heightValueStart) { return -1; }
   if(a.heightValueStart > b.heightValueStart) { return 1; }
   return 0;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to return the comparison result in sortedDate, so just add a `return`,

```
const sortedData = mappedData.sort((a, b) => {
    /* ... */
    return a.heightValueStart < b.heightValueStart
      ? -1
      : a.heightValueStart > b.heightValueStart
      ? 1
      : a.sortColumn < b.sortColumn
      ? -1
      : a.sortColumn > b.sortColumn
      ? 1
      : 0;
  });
```

Comment: You should not use nested ternary expressions. Instead, use `if/else`

Comment: yes in this case since there are only two overall cases, but is it still a bad practice?

Comment: Nested `ternary` may affect performance compare to `if/else`, Check here, The execution time between `ternary` and `if/else`  https://jsperf.com/ternary-vs-switch

Comment: @NeelRathod The jsperf link only shows that the difference is negligible and that it highly depends on the browser version. Though you're right, [never nest ternary](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/28314/183033), but it's to improve readability.